# How redirect old and not exist url to specific url with IIS

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have website and I would like to set up redirect old and not existing url to the special url

old url it does not exist anymore

my config not work !

```
           <rule name="SP" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^domain.com/Product/PoductDetails/bitouyin/probiotin$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="domain.com/Products/biotin" />
            </rule>
```

Requests to old url

```
domain.com/Product/PoductDetails/bitouyin/probiotin
```

to

```
domain.com/Product/bitouyin/probiotin
```

thanks!

Comment: Mistake 1, https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in your rewrite rule are incorrect, you can try this rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Remove PoductDetails" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.+)(PoductDetails)/(.+)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url=domain.com/{R:1}{R:3} appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```